# abas ERP: Limit for table rows in additional database

Tags: erp, abas

Is there a limit for table rows in additional databases in abas erp?
If there is a limit: On which factor the limit is based, how can I calculate the limit and what happens if I try to add more lines by GUI, FO or EDP/EPI?

Can I find it documented in the abas online help? I haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a limit, which is unfortunately not customizable.

You can see a full list of know limitations under help/hd/html/49B.1.4.html
In your specific case the limit of lines in additional databases is 65535.

If you reach the limit, the abas core will show an error message and terminate your current FOP. You can (and should) get the current amount of lines by evaluating the variable tzeilen (currTabRow)

Comment: okay thank you. that is helpful. But you should correct the buffer from G to M in your answer. Is there a difference between tzeilen and ozeilen?

Comment: You can use tzeilen (currTabRow) not with the buffer D. I'm not aware of other differences.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I'm also not aware of any other than the one you mentioned, but you can query ozeilen in a selection list (for master files, not for i.e. sales and purchasing because the rows there aren't physically 'rows'). tzeilen (currTabRow) is buffer related.